# Reading Akavache cache from Swift

Tags: akavache

I'd like to load Akavache data from Swift. I've found `myapp.db{-wal,-shm}` files under `Library/Application Support/MyApp/BlobCache` and can read `myapp.db`, but I'm not sure how to read key-values from the other files.

Is there some documentation somewhere of these file formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Paul Betts, the `Value` field of the `CacheElement` rows are BSON blobs. The files adjacent to the SQLite database file are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Akavache uses SQLite. Look at the source code of Akavache for hints about the schema.

Comment: Yes, I already was reading `myapp.db`. It turns out the `Value` rows are BSON blobs.